# iPhone: Animate circle with UIKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am using a `CircleView` class that basically inherits off `UIView` and implements `drawRect` to draw a circle. This all works, hurrah!

What I cannot figure out though is how to make it so when I touch it (touch code is implemented) the circle grows or pops.  Normally I'd use the UIKit animation framework to do this but given I am basically overriding the `drawRect` function to directly draw the circle.  So how do I animate this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _Color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height));
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Animate?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers depends on what you mean by "grows or pops". When I hear "pop" I assume that the view scales up over a short period of time ans scales back down again to the original size. Something that "grows" on the other hand would scale up but not down again.

For something that scales up and down again over a short period of time I would use a transform to scale it. Custom drawing or not, UIView has build in support for animating a simple transform. If this is what you are looking for then it's not more then a few lines of code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse // reverse back to original value
                 animations:^{
                     // scale up 10%
                     yourCircleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // restore the non-scaled state
                     yourCircleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }];
```

If on the other hand you want the circle to grow a little bit more on every tap then this won't do it for you since the view is going to look pixelated when it scales up. Making custom animations can be tricky so I would still advice you to use a scaling transform for the actual animation and then redraw the view after the animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     // scale up 10%
                     yourCircleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // restore the non-scaled state
                     yourCircleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     // redraw with new value
                     yourCircleView.radius = theBiggerRadius;
                 }];
```

If you really, really want to do a completely custom animation then I would recommend that you watch [Rob Napiers talk on Animating Custom Layer Properties](http://vimeo.com/44986916), his example is even the exact thing you are doing (growing a circle).

Comment: Hi David, what I actually want is for another circle or stroke to grow and fade out when you click the circle.  I figured if I kept the question simple enough I'd get more responses which I could then use to make this work.

Comment: Just used this and I like it a lot, works very well (with the solid circle)

Comment: Note that I had to put `self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);` in the complete handler for it to return (and stay) at its original value otherwise it has a weird "snap" back after the animation

Comment: @Chris Oh, yes. Silly me. I've been doing too much Core Animation where the animations are removed on completion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an animation that expands the ellipse from the centre, try this. In the header, define 3 variables:

```
BOOL   _isAnimating;
float  _time;
CGRect _ellipseFrame;
```

Then implement these 3 methods in the .m file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect; {
  [super drawRect:rect];
  CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _Color.CGColor);
  CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, _ellipseFrame);
}

- (void)expandOutward; {
  if(_isAnimating){
    _time += 1.0f / 30.0f;

    if(_time >= 1.0f){
      _ellipseFrame = self.frame;
      _isAnimating = NO;
    }
    else{
      _ellipseFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.width * _time, self.frame.size.height * _time);
      _ellipseFrame.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0f, self.frame.size.height / 2.0f);
      [self setNeedsDisplay];
      [self performSelector:@selector(expandOutward) withObject:nil afterDelay:(1.0f / 30.0f)];
    }
  }
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer; {
  if(_isAnimating == NO){
    _time = 0.0f;
    _isAnimating = YES;
    [self expandOutward];
  }
}
```

This is the most basic way you can animate the circle expanding from the centre. Look into [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) for a constant sync to the screen if you want more detailed animations. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Hey, I used this and it works, which is great, however it animates the circle from the top left rather than from the middle outwards, any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: If at all possible, you should animate using CAAnimation or UIView animations, particularly for such simple cases as drawing a circle. They are animated outside of your process, and thus are very immune to stutter in your app (and they're a lot simpler -- much less state to keep track of)

Comment: @nevyn Sure. This is more of an example on how to do animation in general. You can keep track of more parameters, and make more complex animations then simple `CAAnimation`

Comment: @Chris, In my haste, I didn't realize that I re-centred the frame in the `CGContextFillEllipseInRect` function. I changed it above, so it should work.

Comment: @msgambel: Even in that case, a CADisplayLink is a requirement rather than a nice-to-have. A 30fps animation is not smooth, not timed to match display redraws, not using real time deltas, and with performSelector: it's scheduled in the wrong run loop mode (animation would pause while scrolling, etc).

Comment: And sorry, this is nitpicking, but: never put implementation details in the header file. Instance variables should almost always be in an ivar block on a class extension (@interface MyClass () { id _myIvar; } in the .m file) or on the implementation block (@implementation MyClass { id _myIvar; } in the .m file)